# Django, display certain hyperlinks based on user group

Tags: html, django, templates

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Welcome to home page.</p>
  <p>{% user.groups.all() %}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

At the moment I'm trying to figure out how I could even get all the user's groups to show on the page. This results in an error.... Invalid block tag on line 5: 'user.groups.all()', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I have tried to do if statements, but it seems break as soon as it meets one condition. For example if user is a part of test1 and test2 groups, I'd like for it to display test1 and test2, but it only displays test1.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Welcome to home page.</p>
  {% if user.groups.all.0.name == "test1" %} 
  <p>test1</p>
  {% if user.groups.all.0.name == "test2" %}
  <p>test2</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you should have used `{{ }}` instead. In order to access groups, do this:

```
 {{ user.groups.all }}
```

and to check for a specific group:

```
{% if desired_group in user.groups.all %}
  some html..
{% endif %}
```

if you want to output specific html for each group:

```
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
   {% if group == desired_group %}
     some html..
  {% endif %}
   ..some more conditions..
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how the 2nd and 3rd block work.. I think I'm thniking about it backwards.. 

So if a user has 'these groups' then display those groups. But I believe the 2nd and 3rd block are doing something else? Or is it intended to be like that..

Comment: I didn't understand what is your aim exacly, but if you want to directly output the group, you can use {{ group }} in for loop.

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand now. For some reason I thought user.groups.all would grab all the groups in the table, but instead it is getting all the groups that pertain to the **user**. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, if you want to get all available groups you may use a context processor or pass groups as context in the view.

Comment: Any idea why the 3rd block isn't working in my case? Doesn't output any html code, no errors either..